# Adding filterBy to p:dataTable causes java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.<init> on postback

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to develop a datatable with lazy loading. 
Unfiltered and filtered records are correctly loaded from the persistence context through the use of UserService (i.e. a simple DAO).
I'm 100% sure the problem is not related to the DAO being used because it has been successfully tested and deployed in other packages.

The error comes out when I try to insert a filter: the collection of filtered items is correctly loaded on the page but it looks like at the end of the process something goes wrong and a NPE is thrown. After that, the table no longer responds to any command.

Thanks for any help!

In the following, the configuration, the view and the controller being used.

**Configuration**

- Wildfly 8.2.0
- JDK 1.8.0_25
- PrimeFaces 5.1

**View (XHTML page)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:form id="UserListForm">
                <p:panel header="#{bundle.ListUserTitle}">
                    <p:dataTable id="UserTable" value="#{userController.users}" var="user" lazy="true" rows="25"
                                 paginator="true" rowKey="#{user.id}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{userController.selected}"
                                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" >

                        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.User_id}" filterBy="#{user.id}">
                           <h:outputText value="#{user.id}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.User_nickname}" filterBy="#{user.nickname}">
                           <h:outputText value="#{user.nickname}"/>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

**Controller**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Named("userController")
@SessionScoped
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    private LazyUserDataModel users;
    private User selected;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        users = new LazyUserDataModel(userService);
    }

    public User getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(User selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public LazyUserDataModel getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(LazyUserDataModel users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

**Lazy Data Model**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

public class LazyUserDataModel extends LazyDataModel<User> {

    private List<User> data;
    private final UserService userService;

    public LazyUserDataModel(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public User getRowData(String rowKey) {
        Long id = Long.valueOf(rowKey);
        for (User u : data) {
            if (u.getId().equals(id))
                return u;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(User u) {
        return u.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
        UserFilterCorrector.correct(filters);
        UserFilter filter = new UserFilter(filters, first, pageSize);
        FilteredDataModel<User> userDataModel = userService.findFilteredList(filter);
        data = userDataModel.getData();
        this.setRowCount(userDataModel.getCount().intValue());
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
11:07:46,348 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-97) Error Rendering View[/user/List.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.<init>(StateHolderSaver.java:96) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.saveAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1746) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.saveMap(ComponentStateHelper.java:378) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.saveState(ComponentStateHelper.java:256) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.saveState(UIComponentBase.java:1552) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIData.saveState(UIData.java:1780) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.saveState(DataTable.java:1520) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$3.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:482) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:472) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:483) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:325) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
```

Comment: I have experienced the same issue. When loading data without lazy loading, there are no issues, but when using lazy loading with database, filtering responds with correct result set with the mentioned exception. Table is stuck after that. PrimeFaces 5.1 on Mojarra 2.2.8.

Answer (score 5):

I solved mine by removing filter value that had null and replacing it with an empty object. You can put breakpoint in the jsf-api/2.2.8/jsf-api-2.2.8-sources.jar!/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.java:1746 and see which value in the filter map is causing the error and then replace it by empty object or remove it. I hope this helps.

Comment: Just an advise if anyone is using eclipse and trying to see which value is null, you can use conditional breakpoint https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F (saves me alot of time debugging)

Answer (score 3):

This must be a bug in the jsf api implementation. As you described in your answer @bcavlin there´s not sufficient null-checks in the source code to store a Map that has any key mapped to a null object. I filed a JIRA issue on this and described it in more dept there, see <strike>JAVASERVERFACES-4088</strike> (old java.net issue) resp. [JAVASERVERFACES-4092](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4092).

Answer (score 0):

I do it:

1. Decompile jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.11.jar
2. Create a new proyect with class javax.faces.components.StateHolderSaver and paste the decompiled code.
3. Add jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.11.jar as library
4. Changue code:

   ```
   public StateHolderSaver(FacesContext context, Object toSave){
      this.className=toSave.getClass().getName();
   ```

   to:

   ```
   public StateHolderSaver(FacesContext context, Object toSave){
      this.className=toSave!=null?toSave.getClass().getName():null;
   ```
5. clean and build
6. Replace compiled StateHolderSaver in jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.11.jar
7. run server and it run ok