# Primefaces 7 Datatable filter not working with array of objects (with minimal setup)

Tags: filter, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2

I know this question has been posted a couple of times, but please take into account the following:

1. I've followed the steps suggested in the other questions' answers and nothing has solved the problem.
2. No logic is being performed in the data getter, as suggested in:
   [java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901882/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cdata-tags-may-not-nest)
3. No templating or paginating is being made in the datatable as suggested in: [Primefaces datatable filtering not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765075/primefaces-datatable-filtering-not-working)
4. I've tried implementing a custom exception handler, but no further information is given in the exceptions.
5. I present the full code so you can copy and paste it and check if it works for you.

So, the problem is: when you try to use the filter in the datatable, it crashes.

Deployed on Tomcat 7. The code works by reverting primefaces to 3.5

**Backing Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DataBean {         
    private List<Object[]> data;
    private List<Object[]> filteredData;

    public DataBean() {}

    // Access methods: init
    public List<Object[]> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<Object[]> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<Object[]> getFilteredData() {
        return filteredData;
    }
    public void setFilteredData(List<Object[]> filteredData) {
        this.filteredData = filteredData;
    }   
    // Access methods: end

    /**
    * The user clicks a button in a menu to go to the list. When he clicks it this method is called
    */
    public String goToList() {                  
        setData( prepareData() );
        setFilteredData( new ArrayList<Object[]>() );
        return "/pages/list?faces-redirect=true";
    }


    /**
     * Returns a list of 10 object arrays. Each array has only one position and that's a String.
     * */
    private List<Object[]> prepareData()  {             
        List<Object[]> l = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Object [] os = new Object[1];
            os[0] = "String " + i;
            l.add(os);
        }

        return l;
    }           
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 
    <h:head>
        <title>Datatable filter problem</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>    
            <p:dataTable
                    filteredValue="#{dataBean.filteredData}"
                    value="#{dataBean.data}" 
                    var="var">                                                              
                        <p:column                       
                        filterBy="#{var[0]}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains">                     
                            <h:outputText value="#{var[0]}"/>
                        </p:column>                                 
                    </p:dataTable>  
        </h:form>    
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
nov 14, 2019 4:49:16 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/pages/list.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.<init>(StateHolderSaver.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.saveAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1694)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.saveMap(ComponentStateHelper.java:378)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.saveState(ComponentStateHelper.java:256)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.saveState(UIComponentBase.java:1501)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.saveState(UIData.java:1753)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.saveState(UIData.java:1333)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.saveState(DataTable.java:1482)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$3.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:874)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
    at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:553)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:300)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:63)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fdsdidgzr.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fdsdidgzr.hibernate3.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.<init>(StateHolderSaver.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.saveAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1694)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.saveMap(ComponentStateHelper.java:378)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.saveState(ComponentStateHelper.java:256)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.saveState(UIComponentBase.java:1501)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.saveState(UIData.java:1753)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.saveState(UIData.java:1333)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.saveState(DataTable.java:1482)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$3.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:874)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
    at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:553)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:300)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:63)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fdsdidgzr.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fdsdidgzr.hibernate3.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
nov 14, 2019 4:49:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Faces Servlet] en el contexto con ruta [/k7] lanzó la excepción [java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest] con causa raíz
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:664)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:172)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:342)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at a.excepcion.CustomExceptionHandler.handle(CustomExceptionHandler.java:44)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fdsdidgzr.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fdsdidgzr.hibernate3.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**JARS**

The code resides in a bigger project, so most of the jars are not used in this particular case.

[image]

Comment: Does it work with @ViewScoped instead of sessionscoped?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast nope :( Same error

Comment: What do your <dependencies> look like?

Comment: @Selaron not using maven. I've updated the question body to show my jars.

Comment: I don't  know why people on s.o. always delete "thanks" from the question's body. Anyway, for all of you that try to help, i say "Thanks!"

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+thanks+removed. Ontopic: JSF 2.1.13 is 7 years old. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl Please try upgrading first (2.3.x releases being in a different location: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.9) And full code is not needed, this seems to be a 'perfect' [mcve], thanks for that

Comment: I hope your tomcat is not 7.0.0. (also 8 years old) and many of your other libs are also rather old. So besides the [mcve] code, create a new empty project in a modern environment with next to no dependencies and retest. Many things that might influence each other in a negative way. But regarding #1, please keep track an mention them like requested in [ask]

Comment: @Kukeltje sadly, its legacy code on a production environment which i don't control. I'll try to upgrade all jars as possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then don't upgrade PrimeFaces either and it still works. Sorry, but I cannot accept (not from you, not from anyone) that states "I want to (and can) update X but cannot/are not allowed to/ have no control over also upgrading Y). Help stops here then for me, sorry (please don't take it personally, but do show this to managers/teamleads/'architects'... and let them take it personally ;-)). Btw, it 'works' here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah, i'll tell them, but is not rare that  managers are not knowledgeable about the things they manage. :(

Comment: Ohhhh sooo true

Comment: Related: [NullPointerException in StateHolderSaver contructor #4092](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4092) - [Adding filterBy to p:dataTable causes java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.<init> on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858911/adding-filterby-to-pdatatable-causes-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-javax-fa#28589516)

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast yup, update mojarra.

Answer (score 1):

I could not pinpoint the exact cause of the error. However, updating mojarra solved it.

Comment: Then I think you had a runtime classpath issue which was solved by a 'clean rebuilding'

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah 123456